# Regex: Sub expressions?

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I need to create a regex that will match this expression:

`replace:sub\:str:new\:Substr`

I have to be careful about not matching other similar looking strings though.  For example, this a different match:

`slice:fromIndex[:toIndex]`

Specifically:

1. The string must begin with `replace:`.  If it does not, then nothing should match.
2. It must match escaped colons: `\:` but not unescaped colons: `:`
3. There must be two matches (the sub string and new substring). For example, in the example string the regex would match: `sub\:str` and `new\:Substr`.
4. The point is to extract out the substring and it's replacement for use later.  The string will always be in the format `replace:<subString>:<replacementString>`.  However, both the subString and the replacementString can have escaped colons `:`, which is why the example includes them.

I've been unable to come up with a solution.  While I'm not an expert at Regex, I'm normally pretty competent.  But so far I've only been able to either ignore `replace:` and simply match on `(?<=\:)(?:\\:|[^:])+` to include both substrings, but I end up matching other patterns as well.  If I change the look behind to `(?<=replace:)` I only match the first substring.  I just can't figure out how to get it to also match that second substring without including the `:` separator.  I suspect I need to nest the expression somehow but I've been completely unsuccessful at it.

Note:  I *can* solve this in the language.  I can simply check if the string has the prefix `replace:` as a separate check.  But I'd really like to do the match completely in Regex if it's possible.

#### Update (some examples)

- `replace:sub\:str:new\:Substr` matches: `sub\:str`, `new\:Substr`
- `replace:subString:replacment` matches: `subString`, `replacement`
- `replace:UserId:user\:ID` matches: `UserId`, `user:ID`
- `replace:UserName:Aaron Hayman` matches: `UserName`, `Aaron Hayman`
- `replace:userId:uid90809y087` matches: `userId`, `uid90809y087`
- `rep:userId:user` matches: none
- `replace:UserName` matches: none
- `slice:908:1098` matches: none

This should give you an example.  As background, after this string is parsed, it would be applied as a kind of filter for another template string.

Comment: Is the whole `sub\:str` a substring with a thing in the middle, or is the `sub\:` (and `new\:` ) part also static? I mean, would `replace:sub\\:(.+):new\\:(.+)` work?

Comment: The point #3 is not so clear. Could you show what do you want? Is it `sub\:str` and `new\:Substr` or something else?

Comment: Examples inputs and outputs ?

Comment: @Toto I've clarified the question and added what the output should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
^replace:(\w+\\:\w+):(\w+\\:\w+)
```

The first group will contain `sub\:str`  and the second `new\:Substr`

New version according to OP's edit:

```
^replace:([^:]+(?:\\:)?[^:]+):([^:]+(?:\\:)?[^:]+)
```

It works for all given test cases

If you don't want `replace` in the whole match, put it in lookbehind:

```
(?<=^replace:)([^:]+(?:\\:)?[^:]+):([^:]+(?:\\:)?[^:]+)
```

Comment: I think OP if after something allowing more than 1 escaped `:`

Comment: This works.  It's not exactly what I asked for, simply because I didn't want to include `replace:` as part of the match, however it allows me to use the regex alone and access the capture groups instead of all matches (which includes the `replace:`).

Comment: @AaronHayman: You could put into lookbehind: `(?<=^replace:)`

Answer (score 1):

The regex that will match all escape sequences you may have in a C string literal will look like

```
replace:([^:\\]*(?:\\.[^:\\]*)*):([^:\\]*(?:\\.[^:\\]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4vVf4b/1)

NOTE: If it must appear at the start of the string, add `^` at the pattern staet.

**Details**:

- `replace:` - a literal char sequence
- `([^:\\]*(?:\\.[^:\\]*)*)` - Capturing group 1 matching

  - `[^:\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `:` and `\`
  - `(?:\\.[^:\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `\\.` - any escaped char (a `\` and any char)
    - `[^:\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `:` and `\`
- `:` - an unescaped `:`
- `([^:\\]*(?:\\.[^:\\]*)*)` - see above.

Answer (score 0):

Quite convoluted, but you can nest lookarounds:

`replace:(.+?(?!(?<=\\):)):(.+(?!(?<=\\):))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BBwvbN/4)

It will ensure that after `replace:` any character is not followed by a `:` not itself preceded by a `\`

**Drawback:**
In case of 3 parts (a third not escaped `:`), The second part will include everything, see the demo for what I mean.